# I am trying to run this query in phpmyadmin but it shows error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting error message = #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where bidder_id = '54'' at line 1

```
UPDATE bid SET estimated_duration = '3 month', bid_amount = '5000', proposal_text = 'hellothere', bid_attachment = '', where bidder_id = '54'
```

Comment: It might be better to store '3' and 'month' as separate entities and the inverted commas around 54 are redundant

Answer (score 3):

Lose the comma in `bid_attachment = '',` to make it

```
UPDATE bid SET estimated_duration = '3 month', bid_amount = '5000',
    proposal_text = 'hellothere', bid_attachment = ''
where bidder_id = '54'`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
UPDATE bid SET estimated_duration = '3 month', bid_amount = '5000', proposal_text = 'hellothere', bid_attachment = '' where bidder_id = '54'
```